# Passwordless SSH not establishing

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install Hadoop on Amazon EC2 Instance CentOS 6.5.I am connected to the instance but want to make the session passwordless SSH. To do this I used the following commands:

ssh-keygen

ssh-copy-id  -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub node01

I get an error saying : Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

I tried logging in as "root" as well as "ec2-user" but it shows the same error.

Could anyone help on this.

Comment: This similar question might help http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/331167/why-cant-i-ssh-copy-id-to-an-ec2-instance

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple scriptlet to ease this process on EC2 - Ubuntu instances.
You can check it out here. 
Just give the machine names and key path, you are done! 
https://github.com/hshinde/pwless